# Custom TAB in Live Agent Console

Tags: liveagent, tab, console

i have this question:

My prechat use liveagent.findOrCreate method to create a 'Info' tab related to my generated transcript. Info is created on a SessionKey and contains fields updated by customer navigation action (so the agent checks which product is added in the cart). If customer complete an order and try to create a second separate order (with the window chat open), i need to create a new Info tab (with the same SessionKey but a different ID) to show to the agent. This new Info Record must be related to the same transcript (the chat window is open). If i try to use liveagent.init i open another chat window with a new agent and i don't want this.

Thanks in advance